# Converting byte array containing ASCII characters to a String

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have a byte array that consists of ASCII characters that I wish to convert to a String. For example:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[8];
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    byte[i] = (byte) ('0' + i);
}
```

myByteArray should contain a string "12345678" after the loop. How do I get this string into a String variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use

```
new String(myByteArray, "UTF-8");
```

String class provides a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) for this.

Side note:The second argument here is the [CharSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)(byte encoding) which should be handled carefully. [More here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html)

Comment: If op wants to convert *from" ASCII, then shouldn't this be `new String(myByteArray, "ISO-8859-1");`? (Assuming 8-bit ASCII/ISO-LATIN rather rather than old 7-bit)

Answer (score 4):

```
String aString = new String(yourByteArray);
```

or

```
String aString = new String(yourByteArray, "aCharSet"); 
//Replacing "aCharSet" with the appropriate chararacter set
```

Easy [See docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Just needed to add in throw/catch blocks or Eclipse will complain