# How to convert Byte string to Ascii String in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have been trying to find hopefully a easy way to convert a buffer value which I have got from a third party software, to an ascii string which will be saved in .json format I don't want the raw hex form. any suggestions?

Here is an example of the buffer contents:

```
5B 7B 22 54 65 73 74 49 6E 50 72 6F 67 72 65 
73 73 22 3A 20 22 4E 6F 22 2C 20 22 41 70 70 
6C 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 20 53 6F 66 74 77 61 
72 65 20 54
```

I want this:

```
[{"TestInProgress": "No", "Application Software T
```

My code:

```
// Dynamically size the buffer according to file size
Buffer buff = new Buffer(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(FileSize)));//5000);

// read DATASIZE from the begginig of the file
jNQfile.read(buff);
Log.i(TAG, "IN AsyncTask in after read in jNQ the path ---------------------------->:" + DirForjNQ );   // debug msg

// Still in this format Message =  Buffer: [5B 7B 22 54 65 ....] 
String Message = buff.toString();
```

This file is copied off a server and the third-party stack sets up and takes care of smb. It’s copied into their buffer. The file is already in .json format. I just want the ASCII characters, not the hex representation, is all.

Comment: String message = new String(buff); String message = new String(buff, "utf-8");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting byte array containing ASCII characters to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583279/converting-byte-array-containing-ascii-characters-to-a-string)

Comment: Why do you say that it is encoded with the ASCII character encoding? Transfering such JSON between parties would be against the standard. If you know it to be ASCII, then fine. If not, the first step would be to find out. You might conclude that the other software complies with the recent standard and is therefore encoded with UTF-8, or complies with the previous standard and the encoding is detectable under that standard, given that it is JSON. Also, why not read it with a JSON library, such as [JSR 374](https://javaee.github.io/jsonp/)?